# Where is SSRS processing carried out?

Tags: reporting-services, remote-server

I googled the heck out of this and never found a suitable answer. What I'm trying to figure out is how much data flows between SSRS and the SQL server. I need to query data at a remote site (with a respectable connection). I'm trying to decide whether I should locate the ReportServer and/or ReportServer DB's at the remote site, all the local site.

Say I have SSRS installed on server A and SQL datasource on Server B. I run a report that returns thousands of rows that are then aggregated in SSRS report. Obviously, the source query runs on the SQL server. What I'm not sure about is where those results are processed (e.g. aggregates computed). Is it done on the SQL server (e.g. does the output get written to temp tables on the SQL server and then all processed there)?

Is it passed back to the SSRS server and done there.

When I have drilldown reports that are collapsed by default, is a round trip to the server required when I drill down (expand a section), or is the data in the client and just not visible?

I'm sure there must be some documentation out there, just can't find it.

Regards

mark

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to find this out for yourself by running a SQL trace on the database server box?

Comment: I don't think I'd be able to isolate the statments, it's a very busy server and SSRS runs with impersonation so all users' report execution is under the same user

Comment: If SSRS runs on its own box, as you indicate, it should get its own SPID that you can filter on.

Comment: Expanding section in drilldown report does not require round trip to datasource (Server B). At this point all the data is in a report. it does however require roundtrip to SSRS (Server A) to re-render a page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know all your expressions processing on ReportServer. You ca read some basic things about SSRS here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157231.aspx

Here is image of SSRS Native mode structure (from MSDN):

[image: From MSDN, SSRS Native mode architecture]